# Не отображается кириллица (FXRuby)

Tags: ruby, кодировка

Я использую для написания GUI на Ruby гем FXRuby, но никак не получается настроить кодировку для распознавания кириллицы, я знаю что это делается через настройку шрифта, но всё одно не отображается

```
    app = FXApp.new
  ffont = FXFont.new(app,"helvetica,110,unicode")
  main = FXMainWindow.new(app,"Memory", :width=>1200, :height=>200 )
  ftext = FXLabel.new(main,"")
  ftext.font = ffont
  ftext.text = [@Memories[0].getEvent,' ',@Memories[0].getDay,' ',@Memories[0].getMonth,' ',@Memories[0].getName].to_s
  app.create
  main.show(PLACEMENT_SCREEN)
  app.run
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: А если так? `ftext.text = [@Memories[0].getEvent, @Memories[0].getDay, @Memories[0].getMonth, @Memories[0].getName].join(" ")`
  `

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, можете объяснить, почему не работало в первом случае, и заработало во втором?

Comment: Оформил Ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, `Array#to_s` с объектами внутри массива работает как `.inspect` -- у меня нет Ruby под рукой, чтоб выразиться точней. Но когда метод `inspect` вызывается у строк с хитрыми символами, вы видите там их шестнадцатиричное представление, как на скриншоте.

```
ftext.text = [@Memories[0].getEvent, @Memories[0].getDay, @Memories[0].getMonth, @Memories[0].getName].join(" ")
```

Такой же вариант кода не вызывает `Array#to_s`, а превращает массив в строку другим методом и дальше отдает ее GUI-библиотеке, которая, как следует из этого, в вашей проблеме виновата не была.

UPD: да, написано, что `to_s` в случае `Array` алиасит `inspect`: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_s